# Extract JavaScript Generated Links in Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi

I'm working on a piece of code in which I require to extract all links from a particular web page. I use the component **EmbeddedWB** because I need to show the current page as well. I have a simple page that is loaded into the EmbeddedWB and contains some scripts that generates some URLs using the function "document.write" of JavaScript. Theoretically I have something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href=#>No problem Here<a/>
 <script Language="JavaScript">
 var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
 document.write("<a href=\"index"+random+".html\"> I Can’t catch this link! </a>");
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

By using the function **ViewPageLinksToStrings (LinksList: TStrings)** of the component I get as expected the URL’s found in the source code, but my intention is to catch the links that are generated with JavaScript too.

What would be the best way to do this? There is any library I can use?

Thank you for your time. John Marko

Comment: Different web browsers can "show page source" differently in this regard. I forget which specific browser but I recall at least one showing you the 'final' source, i.e. what the javascript emitted rather than the js itself. Embedding such a browser may well help you... Alternatively, how about walking the DOM to find links? The DOM must have all the links including those generated by JS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like EmbeddedWB supports Javascript and I found [this article](http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-339.html) in the forum. I contains code which reads the full (Javascript-generated) DOM tree into a variable of type IHTMLDocument2, which is simplified here:

```
procedure MyProcedure(Sender: TObject);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  EmbeddedWB1.Navigate('... some url ...');
  while EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;

  Doc := EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  ...
```